# Error while uploading file

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, file-upload

I m uploading image using post method but every time i find following error:
The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)

Please suggest me the way by which i can resolve this issue:(

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",Base_URL,URL_Upload];
    NSURL* requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSString *filename = imageName;

    //creating request 
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    // set URL
    [request setURL:requestURL];

    // set Content-Type in HTTP header
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    // post body
    NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
    NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);

    if (imageData) {
        [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSString* fileData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", filename];
        NSLog(@"fileData %@",fileData);
        [postbody appendData:[fileData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postbody appendData:imageData];
        [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

   [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

     // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [request setHTTPBody:postbody];

    // set the content-length
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postbody length]];
   [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

     _connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [_connection start];
    if (_connection) {
        _reposnseData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
```

Comment: Try using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@registration.php",appdel.baseUrl];
  NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str];

  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
 [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
 NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
 NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"a.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imgData]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//  parameter username

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"username\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[userName.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


//  parameter token
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"email\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[eMail.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// parameter method
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"pass\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[passWord.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


//parameter method
NSLog(@"%@",countryCode);
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"country\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[countryCode dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// close form
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];


NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
// NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://********/web-services/register_user.php?firstname=%@&lastname=%@&email=%@&password=%@&location=india&device=IPHONE",details.fname,details.lname,details.emailAddress,details.password];
// urlString=[urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

UIImage *image=details.pic;
NSData *imageData =UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1);
double my_time = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)(my_time)];
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", @"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile_pic\"; filename=\"", imageName, @".jpg\"\r\n\""];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:string] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString*s11=   [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *responseDictionary1;
responseDictionary1 = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:s11 error:nil];
```

Comment: when we are uploading from iOS. server side code should be different